# Importing data using Numpy genfromtext and formatting column with datetime

Tags: arrays, numpy, datetime, python-datetime, genfromtxt

I have a long text file that I am importing with numpy genfromtext:

```
00:00:01 W 348 18.2 55.9 049 1008.8 0.000 
00:00:02 W 012 12.5 55.9 049 1008.8 0.000 
00:00:03 W 012 12.5 55.9 049 1008.8 0.000
00:00:04 W 357 18.2 55.9 049 1008.8 0.000 
00:00:05 W 357 18.2 55.9 049 1008.8 0.000 
00:00:06 W 339 17.6 55.9 049 1008.8 0.000 

testdata = np.genfromtxt(itertools.islice(f_in, 0, None, 60),\
                         names=('time','ew','d12','s12','t12','p12'.....)

time = (testdata['time'])
```

This is organizing all the data into an array. The first column of data in the file is a timestamp for each row. In the text file it is formatted as `00:00:00` so in format (`%H:%m:%s`). However in the actual array that is generated, it turns it into `1900-01-01 00:00:00` . When plotting my data with time, I cannot get it to drop the Y-m-d.

I have tried `time = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')`
and
`dt.datetime.strptime(time.decode('ascii'), '%H:%M:%S')`

Both do nothing. How can I turn my whole array of times to keep the original %H:%m:%s format without it adding in the %Y-%m-%d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: based on data provided, you can import your file like this:

```
str2date = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.decode("utf-8"), '%H:%M:%S').time()

data = np.genfromtxt(itertools.islice(f_in, 0, None, 60), dtype=None,names=('time','ew','d12','s12','t12','p12'.....), delimiter=' ', converters = {0: str2date})

print(data['time'])
```

output:

```
00:00:01
```

Note than you would need to `.decode("utf-8")` your input to `str2date` since it accepts bytes. You can set your `dtype` in `np.genfromtxt()` according to your specific file content.

You can also use this if your data is in right format:

```
dt.datetime.strptime(time,"%H:%M:%S").time()
```

Comment: What would "start" be in this instance?

Comment: @Jonathon editted. Just your time. Same as your code. just add `.time()` to end of it to extract hours:minutes:secs/msecs. You might need to decode `time` too (not sure what format you saved your time in your data)

Comment: I tried that before and get ```strptime() argument 1 must be str, not numpy.ndarray```. When I do tostring(), I get ```strptime() argument 1 must be str, not bytes```

Comment: @Jonathon Can you provide a sample of your data here?

Comment: I included it in the question

Comment: @Jonathon Please fine my edit to the post if it helps. Thank you.